# Angular ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

[image]i am trying to filter my table data based on the input text, but some how it's not working. Kindly help please.

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">search
    <input type="text" ng-model="search_text">
    Searching for :: {{search_text}}
   </div>  
  <Table>   
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Item ID</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>       
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search_text">
        <td>{{item.item[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{item.item[1] }}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you please show us the object (items) ,,

Comment: Please show us how your data is structured.

Comment: any errors in console ? Your code seems to be correct

Comment: have added my Data structure, above ( using firebase ) and there is no error in console

Comment: What is "not working"?

Comment: @MGA, are you getting incorrect result or getting an error in console. this should be very simple if you tell exactly? waiting

Comment: @immirza , it seems that filter only works with array and not with objects as i mentioned the structure above ( 1.3 X version doesn't throw any error in console but 1.4X does says its expecting array

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the version your angularjs you are using or any errors in console.

Your code seems to work and is correct indeed.

```
  //array of items containing itemID and its quantity
  $scope.items = [{
                    item:['chair',45]
                  },
                  {
                    item:['bed',23]
                  },
                  {
                    item:['laptop',8]
                  }]
```

Here's the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XjFu0ndHNq641jw7yIs1?p=preview)

The table data is indeed filtering with respect to value you enter in textbox

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 1.1.3 you can use:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{item[0]: search_text}">
```

This will compare it to the object property item[0] in your object.
If you want the exact match, you can set the filtering to true by adding:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{item[0]: search_text}:true">
```

Comment: Actually when i updated my angular version from 1.3 to 1.4.3 version it's throwing error as " Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {"-JuQxmosAMBeQitsYevP":{"item":["chair","5"]},"-JuQxoG04-WFcrLR5D6G":{"item":["Bed","10"]},"-JuQxrGLi8O8vZjyQ87O":{"item":["Laptop","2"]},"$id":"items","$priority":null}"  ... so how can i save my data as array in firebase ?